# WCF: How to write attributes in definitions section of WSDL files?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, asmx

I'm trying to generate WSDL file programmatically from scratch and it almost works fine. One of the points that I don't know how to do is to write my own attributes in definitions section. I mean on this section of WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"...>
```

I use the following C# code:

```
System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription wsdl = new System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription();

System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema xmlSchema = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema();
xmlSchema.SourceUri = "PO.xsd";
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaImport xmlSchemaImport = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaImport();
xmlSchemaImport.Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/PO";
xmlSchemaImport.SchemaLocation = "PO.xsd";
xmlSchema.Includes.Add(xmlSchemaImport);
wsdl.Types.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);

...

wsdl.Write("POService.wsdl");
```

What does it happen? The attributes in definitions section are automatically generated by the code, but I need to add some custom constructions there.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Goran